# How to cache layer activations in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I train a NN in which first layers have fixed weights (non-trainable) in Keras.

Computation performed by these layers is pretty intensive during training. It makes sense to cache layer activations for each input and reuse them when same input data is passed on next epoch to save computation time.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour in Keras?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could separate your model into two different models. For example, in the following snippet `x_` would correspond to your intermediate activations:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
import numpy as np


nb_samples = 100
in_dim = 2
h_dim = 3
out_dim = 1

a = Input(shape=(in_dim,))
b = Dense(h_dim, trainable=False)(a)
model1 = Model(a, b)
model1.compile('sgd', 'mse')

c = Input(shape=(h_dim,))
d = Dense(out_dim)(c)
model2 = Model(c, d)
model2.compile('sgd', 'mse')


x = np.random.rand(nb_samples, in_dim)
y = np.random.rand(nb_samples, out_dim)
x_ = model1.predict(x)  # Shape=(nb_samples, h_dim)

model2.fit(x_, y)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing as it looks like Keras does not support feature like I need in the first place.